# How do I partition the 120GB SSD hard drive with Ubuntu 20.* as OS so that the root has enough space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, ubuntu-20.04

I never quite understood the ubuntu partitioning ever. As I see the root has 11GB of my 120GB hard drive even if the partition 1 on my hard drive is at least 70GB. How can I assign a partition space to the root so root has enough space? It usually fills up quickly with apps and installables and then I'm in need of installing Ubuntu again.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just create custom partitions. Make a `/root` partition of 50GB, a `/boot` partition of 500MB and the rest as the /home partition. That way you will have enough space for everything including 70GB for your files. You can always have your root partition smaller if you wish like 20GB or 30GB. You will have space for some time with that.

Swap partition is used to swap pages out of RAM when RAM is full. Linux doesn't use this much RAM. Depending on how much RAM you have, you may wish to have some swap space. You can always choose 3.5GB for swap and take that either on the `/root` or `/home` partition.

So the `/root` partition is used for all installations as you said. The `/home` partition is used for your files and all stuff you save as a user of the system. The `/boot` partition stores GRUB the bootloader and some other files required to boot the system. I explained the swap partition above. So I think you have all the info required to set up a custom partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a misunderstanding regarding partition size and folder size?

Seems like the root partition is 70 GB whereas the root folder is 11GB.

Partition size is always the maximum available storage, folder size is always the used storage.

The root folder takes up 11GB. plus ca. 58 GB free space makes up to ca. 70 GB partition size.

There's plenty of free storage (for now).

Anyways, if you want to assign more, I would not suggest making dedicated home partitions and would rely on a swapfile instead of a swap partition. This approach makes your storage usage more flexible.

Comment: What does “ca.” mean?